# Substring in sql server on numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column name called "PersonNameID"

which contains two values

```
ABCD-GHJI
ABHK-67891
HJKK-HJJJMH-8990
```

I have to extract only the first part of the "PersonNameID" which contains number after "-".Ideally my output should be

```
ABCD-GHJI
ABHK
HJKK-HJJJMH
```

but when I use following code :

```
SELECT TOP 100

     CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100),

     SUBSTRING(PersonNameID, 1,
          CASE
               WHEN CHARINDEX('-', PersonNameID) > 0 
                    THEN LEN(PersonNameID) - 
                         LEN(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(PersonNameID), 1, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(PersonNameID))))) 
                    ELSE LEN(PersonNameID)

          END
     )
     ) AS New_PersonNameID
FROM Person
```

I get the output as

```
ABCD
ABHK
HJKK
```

Any modifications to the above code to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the above situation...

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE(
Person_NAME_Original VARCHAR(500),
Person_NAME_Modified VARCHAR(500)
)           

INSERT INTO @Person (Person_NAME_Original,Person_NAME_Modified)

SELECT top 1000 PersonNameID,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID) = 0
                 THEN PersonNameID
            WHEN iSNUMERIC( rIGHT(PersonNameID ,CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(PersonNameID))-1))=1
                 THEN  LEFT(PersonNameID, len(PersonNameID) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(PersonNameID) )-1)
            ELSE PersonNameID
       END AS New_PersonNameID
from Person                                

select * from @Person
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern matching to find the numeric ones and then work out where the numeric

```
SELECT
    LEFT(PersonNameID,
            CASE WHEN PersonNameID LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND CHARINDEX('-', PersonNameID) > 0
            THEN 
                CHARINDEX('-', PersonNameID)-1 
            ELSE 
                LEN(PersonNameID) 
            END) AS NewPersonId
FROM 
    Person
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE(
        PersonNameID VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Person VALUES ('ABCD-GHJI'),('ABHK-67891')

SELECT           top 100 
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID ) = 0
        THEN PersonNameID
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(PersonNameID,LEN(PersonNameID) - CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID ))) = 0
        THEN PersonNameID
    ELSE LEFT(PersonNameID, CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID )-1)
END AS New_PersonNameID
from @Person
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5839)

Comment: Suppose the name  Duthja - AEPD - 700358492 the above query will give the entire thing

Comment: Did you try it? Have a look at this example. It seems to work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5881

Comment: Yes I tried Duthja - AEPD - 700358492 will remain Duthja - AEPD - 700358492

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT TOP 100
             (CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID )>0 AND 
          iSNUMERIC( rIGHT(PersonNameID ,CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID )))=1
        THEN 
        lEFT(PersonNameID ,CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID)-1)
       ELSE  
        PersonNameID
         END
        )  AS New_PersonNameID
            FROM Person
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/432e3/1)

Answer (score 1):

Any numeric after '-' will be deleted. You can play with the patindex pattern to suit your need.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%-_[0-9]%',PersonNameID)>0 THEN LEFT(PersonNameID,CHARINDEX('-',PersonNameID)-1)
         ELSE PersonNameID
    END 
    AS New_PersonNameID
FROM Person
```